# virtualenv Error: FileNotFoundError, No such File /home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-xxxxxxxx/bin/python

Tags: virtualenv, pipenv

What could cause this issue, are you familiar with this error message?
I googled and the only similar issues are years old and apparently fixed.

```
pipenv --python 3   
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: /project/Pipfile
Using /usr/bin/python3 (3.10.6) to create virtualenv...
⠼ Creating virtual environment...created virtual environment CPython3.10.6.final.0-64 in 187ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-xxxxxxxx, clear=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=latest, setuptools=latest, wheel=latest, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/user/.local/share/virtualenv/seed-app-data/v1.0.1)
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator

✔ Successfully created virtual environment!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pipenv", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/cli/options.py", line 58, in main
    return super().main(*args, **kwargs, windows_expand_args=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1637, in invoke
    super().invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 26, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 207, in cli
    ensure_project(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/utils/project.py", line 32, in ensure_project
    ensure_virtualenv(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/utils/virtualenv.py", line 160, in ensure_virtualenv
    do_create_virtualenv(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/utils/virtualenv.py", line 105, in do_create_virtualenv
    project._environment = Environment(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/environment.py", line 80, in __init__
    self._base_paths = self.get_paths()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/environment.py", line 384, in get_paths
    c = subprocess_run(command)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pipenv/utils/processes.py", line 72, in subprocess_run
    return subprocess.run(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 501, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 969, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1845, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/project-xxxxxxxx/bin/python'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is typically caused by one of three things:

1. Conflicting `python` versions
2. A bad setuptools install
3. A corrupted pipfile lock

To fix #1, you can try being more specific about which version of python you want (i.e `pipenv --python 3.9`), or uninstalling and reinstalling python3.

To fix #2, you can run `pip uninstall -y setuptools`

To fix #3, you can run `pipenv --rm && rm Pipfile* && exit`. Please note that this will **PERMANENTLY DELETE** the pipfile lock and pipenv info.

After the step you chose, run `pipenv` again.

Alternatively, you could switch to something more trusted like `venv` (see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html))